# Интеграция векторного изображения в Android Studio

Tags: android, svg, material-design

Было создано векторное изображение для фона в `toolbar` в Inscape. При добавлении "на прямую" студия не розпознает тэг `svg`. При конвертации в vector drawable с помощью онлайн ресурсов проблема не исчезает - студия не розпознает некоторые тэги. Как интегрировать изображение именно в растре?

Comment: в андроид студио есть vector image asset.- сгенерирует вам xml drawable для svg файла.но из личного опыта, довольно часто генерирует их криво

Comment: @SviatVolkov, не могу найти vector image asset. Переконвертировал через илюстратор - резутьтат тот же.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

Answer (score 1):

делаешь svg через illustrator, а добавляешь в студию через vector image asset.

ну и в грэдле

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```